# What should I do when I get error "HTTP 403 from proxy after CONNECT" using cURL in PHP?

Tags: php, curl, telegram-bot

I'd like to see my messages using Telegram API, like "/getupdates or "/getme", and I read I have to user cURL, but unfortunately I don't see anything on the page... blank page.
So what's wrong whit my code blow here?

```
<?php

$botToken = "172894271:****myTelegramBotId****";
$botUrl  = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $botToken;

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $botUrl."/geupdates");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

//url error: Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT
if(curl_errno($ch)) { echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);} 

echo $result;

?>
```

The error is: "url error: Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT"

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the to of the page after `<?php`. Also, evalulate the error response if any: `if(curl_errno($ch)) { echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);}`

Comment: You mean "ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);" ?

Comment: No. I mean [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: Nothing, no errors :/

Comment: look at where you check for errors, before curl is even run

Comment: The `curl_errno` check needs to come **after** `$result = curl_exec($ch);` as the handler won't have been initialized until that point to make a comparison against it. Also, I find it odd that no errors come about when `$ch` isn't set prior to you executing `curl_errno($ch)`, so let's also try, `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 0):

You should get a number of warnings if the error reporting is enabled.

For example, this one:

```
Warning: curl_setopt() expects exactly 3 parameters, 2 given in ..\index.php on line X
```

for this line specifically:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors",1);
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER);
```

In addition, where `$handle` comes from? it should be `$ch`, no?

Comment: o.O? Sorry I didn't catch what you said... the error that I got is: "url error: Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT"

Answer (score 0):

in apache/conf/extra there will be file httpd_proxy.conf, set

```
ProxyRequests On
```

and below that add :

```
AllowCONNECT port[-port] [port[-port]]
```

For ex :

```
ProxyRequests On
AllowCONNECT 443 112 1002
```

1002 is destination port, restart apache and try